# Gzip compression for WebSphere application server 8.0

Tags: primefaces, websphere, gzip, jsf-2.2, websphere-8

I am using primefaces 6.0 and myfaces. I am using WebSphere application server 8.0. I want to know gzip compression technique for html,js and css files using was 8.0

Comment: Use OmniFaces (you should anyway ;-))

Comment: I agree with @Kukeltje - http://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/GzipResponseFilter

Comment: I agree with @wtlucy (no idea where my link to the example went)

Comment: i am trying to use omnifaces GzipResponseFilter but i am gettting this exception. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter

Answer (score 0):

You have to obtain and configure a third-party gzip compression filter. It's not provided by the server for applications.

Comment: i have used omnifaces gzip filter.there is lot difference in transfered file size but content downloading time is more.